# how can i use GetAdaptersAddresses() to send ip address

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tcp, client-server, ip-address

i am trying to create a server and client program in c++ using TCP where the server sends its ip address to a web host, the client can then access the web host and get the list of servers. 
i am trying to use GetAdaptersAddresses() function to send the server's ip address but i don't really know how the function works. I know it needs 5 parameters but i don't know what values to put for those.

here is all the server code:

```
    #define WEBSITE         "server.x10host.com"    // Full website URL, withouth HTTP (raises exe size)
#define WEBPAGE         "/Server.php"               // The page of the Server Script (proceed with '\')


#define cAddIP          0       // Send this to the server, to add the IP to the list.
#define cRemIP          1       // Send this to the server, to remove the IP from the list.
#define cGetIPs         2       // Send this to the server, to get the list of all IPs.


SOCKET ListeningSocket;
SOCKADDR_IN ServerAddr;

int Port = 7171;
int MyIP;                       // Hold's the computers external IP (EG on an NAT)

// -------------------------




char* WebPost(char Website[], char Webpage[], char Request[], int RetLen) {
    // Sends an HTTP Post request with POST Data...
    // Absolutly NOT error checking, which needs fixing!

    SOCKET WebSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    struct hostent *WebHost;
    WebHost = gethostbyname(Website);
    if (WebHost == NULL) {

        if (WSAGetLastError() == WSANOTINITIALISED)
            printf("Error Not Connected!");
        else
            printf("Error: %d", WSAGetLastError());

        Sleep(1000);
        exit(0);

    }
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port   = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)WebHost->h_addr);
    connect(WebSocket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr));


    char PostRequest[1024];

    sprintf(PostRequest,
        "POST %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: %s\r\n"
        "Content-Length: %hu\r\n"
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
        "\r\nD=%s\0",
        Webpage, Website,
        strlen(Request)+2, Request
    );

    send(WebSocket, PostRequest, strlen(PostRequest), 0);


    // Get return data ----------

    char* Data = new char[RetLen];
    recv(WebSocket, Data, 4, 0);

    for (;;) {                          // Skip HTTP headers...

        Data[0] = Data[1];
        Data[1] = Data[2];
        Data[2] = Data[3];

        recv(WebSocket, &Data[3], 1, 0);

        if (Data[0] == '\r' && Data[1] == '\n'
        &&  Data[2] == '\r' && Data[3] == '\n')
            break;

    }

    int DataLen = recv(WebSocket, Data, RetLen, 0);
    Data[DataLen] = '\0';   // Return the data...

    shutdown(WebSocket, 2);
    closesocket(WebSocket);
    return Data;

}



void ServStart() {

    WSADATA wsaData; 

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        printf("Server: WSAStartup failed with error %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Server: The Winsock DLL found!\n");
    printf("Server: The current status is %s.\n\n", wsaData.szSystemStatus);

    if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 ) {
        printf("Server: The dll do not support the Winsock version %u.%u!\n", LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion),HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion));
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Server: The dll supports the Winsock version %u.%u!\n", LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion),HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion));


    // Start listening -----------------------------------------------
    ListeningSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (ListeningSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Server: Error at socket, error code: %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
    ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(ListeningSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Server: bind failed! Error code: %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListeningSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    if (listen(ListeningSocket, 5) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Server: listen: Error listening on socket %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListeningSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    char SendBuf[32];
    MyIP = GetAdaptersAddresses();      // Get my IP
    sprintf(SendBuf, "%hhu|%s", cAddIP, MyIP);              // Send the server the IP
    WebPost(WEBSITE, WEBPAGE, SendBuf, 0);

    printf("Server: listening for connections...\n\n");

}

void ShutDown() {               // Shut down the server (tells the web server I am offline)

    char SendBuf[32];           // Remove my IP from the list of online servers...
    sprintf(SendBuf, "%hhu|%s", cRemIP, MyIP);
    WebPost(WEBSITE, WEBPAGE, SendBuf, 0);

    printf("Successful shutdown\n");
    Sleep(1000);

    WSACleanup();

}
```

can someone please help me with the code for this function?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to send your own IP address? A web-client making any form of connection will send a packet that contains it's "return address" - which also is the address of that server. Unless of course you are inside a firewall, where things gets complicated, but in that case you probably don't WANT to send your IP address of the local machine, but the one that the firewall provides.

All you need is something like this on the server:

```
<?php

echo "Your address is " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "<br/>";

?>
```

(If you want to try it with a random machine, you can try this: http://linuxhost.matsp.co.uk/calculator/my_ip.php)

Comment: but that gets the external ip address. i want the address of the computer running the server - IPv4 Address

Comment: That means you are behind a firewall (or router with firewall built in, or something like that), and thus you WANT the external address of the server. My local IP for the machine that script is on 192.168.0.66 will not get to that machine from the outside.  81.158.216.91 will get to that machine, because that is the external IP address. So, if you want someone to "select a server", you need the external address.

Comment: well i'm only using the local network so i would need the local IP for each machine

Comment: Then place your server on the inside too... ;)

Answer (score 0):

got it to work 
just needed to set MyIP to `MyIP = inet_ntoa(addr);`